# Clash in Flutter library functions on a platform I'm happy to drop

Tags: flutter

I'm building a web app with dart/flutter.

I'd like to use [file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker) with [rich_clipboard](https://pub.dev/packages/rich_clipboard) but when I try and add the latter I get this message…

```
flutter pub add rich_clipboard
Because rich_clipboard_windows >=1.0.2 depends on win32 >=2.5.1 <5.0.0 and rich_clipboard_windows <1.0.2 depends on win32 ^2.5.1,
  every version of rich_clipboard_windows requires win32 >=2.5.1 <5.0.0.
And because file_picker >=5.3.2 depends on win32 ^5.0.2, file_picker >=5.3.2 is incompatible with rich_clipboard_windows.
Because rich_clipboard <1.0.0 depends on rich_clipboard_windows ^0.0.1 and rich_clipboard >=1.0.0 depends on rich_clipboard_windows
  ^1.0.0, every version of rich_clipboard requires rich_clipboard_windows ^0.0.1 or ^1.0.0.
Thus, file_picker >=5.3.2 is incompatible with rich_clipboard.
So, because [] depends on both file_picker ^5.3.2 and rich_clipboard any, version solving failed.
```

I don't need to target win32 - does that enable a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing file picker veraion to any pubspec.yaml

```
file_picker : any
```

Then flutter clean and flutter pub get. If this doesnt work then downgrade file picker to a smaller version

```
file_picker : 5.2.0
```

Comment: thanks for this - it'll come in handy if I have other version clashes between libraries. Flutter's error message let me to mistakenly believe it had checked all versions of these libraries rather than fixing file_picker at ^5.3.2

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs due to incompatible dependencies between the `rich_clipboard` and `file_picker`. So not targeting win32 won't fix your problem. You can downgrade `file_picker` to `5.3.0` until `file_picker` or `rich_clipboard` update their dependencies to be compatible with newer versions of `win32` package.

In your pubspec.yaml set `file_picker` as following

```
file_picker: ^5.3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find an alternative to `rich_clipboard` so I swapped out `file_picker` for `file_selector`.

I then did:

```
flutter clean
flutter upgrade
dart run build_runner build
```